# Confusing related rates problem

Tags: calculus

***Disclaimer: I am not a lazy student trying to get free internet homework help. I am an adult autodidact polymath who is independently learning Calculus from a textbook.  I am deeply grateful to the members of this community for their time.***

Q: (Verbatim)  "The radius of a sphere is increasing at a rate of 2 inches per minute.
In terms of surface area, what is the rate of change of the volume of the sphere?"

*(Phrasing of the question is confusing, first of all)*

I know that $V=\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3$
I also know $SA=4\pi r^2$

So, $\frac{dV}{dt}=4\pi r^2\frac{dr}{dt}$

I also know that $\frac{dr}{dt}=2$

So, $\frac{dV}{dt}=4\pi r^2(2)=8\pi r^2$

But then the solution says "Since $S=\pi r^2$, $\frac{dV}{dt}=28 in^3/min$"

No clue how they got 28.
I only have seen related rates where they give you a fixed value at some point in time, which then gets substituted.

Any hints here?

Comment: There is a typo in the volume -- should be a $r^3$, not $r^4$.

Comment: I would have no problem with this if it were homework.  You have shown what you have tried and identified well where the problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are fine down to $\frac {dV}{dt}=8\pi r^2$.  As they ask for it in terms of surface area, I would make that into $\frac {dV}{dt}=2S$.  I think the $8$ is a typo for $S$

Answer (score 2):

I think they meant $2S$. Looks a lot like 28.

$$\frac{dV}{dt}=4\pi r^2\frac{dr}{dt} = S \frac{dr}{dt} = 2S$$

EDIT: oops. I should refresh more often ;0